# EC2 Scaling tips and advice

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need some tips/ advice.

We need to scale our web application that currently has around 400 users in total to
one that must handle at least 15k user connections per day.
Each of those users will stay less than 1 hour connected.

Currently we have an EC2 instance at amazon (t2.large).
I know that it's a lot to suppose, but:

- With those numbers, what instance do you recommend?
  My plan is to upgrade gradually, but I need to know where to start.
  From a hardware point of view, if we need more users, we only have to do a couple clicks and upgrade our instance?
- Should I contact with AWS or some freelancer/ consulting company specialized in AWS?

I've never scaled an applications with those numbers so I'm not sure what to do now.

Any advice will help.
Thanks :)

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without knowing things like how much server load a single user generally creates, which is entirely dependent on things like the software you are running on the server which you neglected to mention in your post. In general though, you need to be looking at adding more servers and placing them all behind a load balancer instead of just increasing the size of a single server.

Answer (score 0):

is there any AWS Service that you are using for infra? For example; EKS, Elastic Beanstalk, ECS etc. If yes, which one? Because depends on the service you will be using, the effort for upgrading instance type can change.

For instance type perspective, it really depends on your application's need, is it memory-heavy or cpu-heavy, or does it require lots of processing? t type instances are basic instances for AWS Cloud, they don't serve much. Depend on the application, you may want to think c type or m type instances to prevent any performance issues.

I think it's unnecessary to create a budget for consulting at this point. You can do it by reading AWS documents.